# Load balancing email server

Tags: domain-name-system, email, load-balancing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DNS e-mail load balancing](https://serverfault.com/questions/381474/dns-e-mail-load-balancing)

My scenario is:

```
php-script(mail originating) -> DNS load balancer (vps server).--vps1(relayhost 1)
                                                              |--vps2(relayhost 2)
                                                              |--vps3(relayhost 3)
```

When I'm sending text mail (size ~8 KB) from a php script to a load balancer that is balancing the load of mails and delivering them to relay servers. I have relayed 40,000  mails for a mail campaign by using this.

But when I embedded an image in my mail (image size ~160 KB) the load balancer does not deliver any mail to clients.

Is this an issue of mail size or could it be another issue?

Comment: but inthis i have described my scenerio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is entirely dependent upon what kind of load balancer you are using and what its configuration is. Since you haven't told us anything about that setup, it's impossible to help you.

However, let's talk about something slightly different, and yet to your benefit. If you have an image to place in your emails, you would likely benefit much more from placing it on a web server and embedding an HTML `<img>` tag in the emails. That keeps your email size down and also gives you an ability to track open rates and other statistics.

Comment: sorry for that my vps server configuration as follow..                                                            Operating system=centos5.7                                                      Ram=700 MB    and disc space =18GB.                                I have done load balancing  of mails by giving same mx record preference to each of the vps to which the load was to be balanced by the laod balancer server.